# How to get the path of the newest file among the set of files which contains the same ID?

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script

I want to write a script which will take the ID as an input from the user. Based on that input it will search the directories to match a file which contains the given id. Now, the directory has more than 10 files, but all contains same ID. So, if I use `grep` it will only give me the files in sorted order. I don't want to display all the files, except the *latest* file in the directory which contains that id. Suppose I have `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4`, `a5`, `a6`, etc. files. All files has some info but only their ID is different.

I tried `grep -lr "$read" | ls -ltr`, but this renders only files in ascending order, not achieving complete purpose. I want clue/suggestion how would i work for rendering the latest file with the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few approaches:

- If all files are in the same target directory (`$dir`), it is trivial:

  ```
  newest=$(ls -1tr $(grep -Hl "$read" "$dir") | tail -n 1)
  ```
- If you also need to go into subdirectories:

  ```
  newest=$(ls -1tr $(find . -type f -exec grep -Hl "$read" {} \;) | tail -n 1)
  ```

Both of the examples above use `tail -n 1` to print only the last line of the sorted `ls` output. However, parsing `ls` is a [very bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and should generally be avoided. Here are a few more complex but safer methods that can deal with arbitrary file names:

- This uses a few tricks, I need to use the `{ }` syntax to capture the variable (see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)). The `IFS=` and `-r` make sure we can deal with weird file names, and `stat` to get the file's modification time. The newest file is saved in the variable `$newest`.

  ```
  mdate=0; 
  fdate=0;
  newest=$(find . -type f -exec grep -Hl foo {} \; | 
  { 
      while IFS= read -r file; do 
          fdate=$(stat -c %Y "$file"); 
          if [ "$fdate" -gt "$mdate" ]; then 
              latest="$file"; 
              mdate="$fdate"; 
          fi; 
      done; 
      echo "$latest"; 
  })
  ```